# Jenkins plugin HttpRequest returns 500 error

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am writing a groovy script which has a method which is invoked from my Jenkins pipeline stage. This function calls an API which has a Basic Auth Header and a post body.

This piece of code returns me 500 on Jenkins, but works correct on Postman.

```
def callAPI(String SN_CREDENTIALS, String description, String name ) {

   String auth = SN_CREDENTIALS.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
   def body_data = """{
                         "start_date": "${utc_startdate}",
                         "end_date": "${utc_enddate}",
                         "description": "${Description}",
                      }
                    """
  def url = 'https://example.com/api/sn_chg_rest/change/standard/' + id
  def response = httpRequest url: url, acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
    contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
    httpMode: 'POST',
    requestBody: body_data,
    customHeaders: [[name: 'Authorization', value: "Basic ${auth}"]]

 }
```

where SN_CREDENTIALS are the credentials saved on Jenkins.

**Jenkinsfile**

```
environment {
    SN_CREDENTIALS = credentials('SNCreds')
  }

stage{
    steps{
        script{
              buildTicketScript.callAPI("${SN_CREDENTIALS}",description,name)
        }
    }
 }
```

Response Code: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Is there something wrong with the piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. There was a problem with my body_data, one of the values had "new line" and it wasn't parsing it correctly. Removed the new line and it works perfectly fine